# JS - Reloading chat data with setInterval method

Tags: javascript, ajax, client-side

Let say we are building a web-chat app, is it normal to update the view using `setInterval` method? Like in every second the JS will update the HTML view by fetching the latest data from the server.

Or, is there any other way which is more practical to update the view?

Comment: Try to use web sockets instead of AJAX. http://socket.io/

Comment: Have you done any web research?

Comment: idmean, I did but somehow I didn't understand much

Comment: Andrey Etumyan, thanks will look on that